# Modify a respose returned by an API endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working with this [live REST-API endpoint](http://api.vidyarajkumari.com/images/) that returns JSON data in the format

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "image": "https://vidyabati.s3.amazonaws.com/image/FB_IMG_1598418232008.jpg",
      "caption": "",
      "feature": false,
      "album": 15,
      "created_at": "2020-09-13T11:44:29.802475+05:30",
      "updated_at": "2020-09-13T11:44:29.802506+05:30"
    },
    // And repeated so on
  ]
}
```

I create a React component that consumes this data as such

Component.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://api.vidyarajkumari.com/images/";

export default function Component() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(BASE_URL)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setImages(response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error message", err);
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {
        images.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="col-md-4 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
              <div className="project" style={{backgroundImage: 'url({item.image})'}}>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: How do I set the state to access the `images` array from the api using axios?

Comment: _"each individual array from the `images` array"_ What do you mean? Which individual arrays?

Comment: Also, Axios nest the body into a `data` property, so you probably want to save: `setImages(response.data)` or even `response.data.images`.

Comment: What is happening currently when you run this code? And what does the `console.log(response)` look like in output?

Comment: @MikeAbeln The request always goes to the .catch block so error. I have no idea what is returned by the .then response

Comment: @EmileBergeron Since the api didn't return an array of objects, but an array of objects nested within an object (images in this case). So my goal is to make the setImages within the .then set the images as an array.

Comment: @dEBAM It seems like your immediate issue is either dealing with your server's response or the request for the data, as it is hitting the `.catch` block. Are you sure that sending a request just to the `BASE_URL` is valid? You may need to request each asset that you need individually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EmileBergeron provided the tip. Using `setImages(response.data.images)` was the solution